# Use floating point button to create menu item

Tags: android

I'm making a counter app want to be able to have a plus button (which I have designed) open up a dialog box that allows the user to enter a title and click add, and then have this new counter automatically add itself to the menu bar (the 3 dashes in the right top corner.)

I have 0 coding experience and don't know how to attempt this, any help or references to videos that I can't find (I've looked) would be greatly appreciated.

```
MENU ITEM CODE:
 <item
     android:id="@+id/nav_counter1"
     android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
     android:title="Counter 1" />
 <item

FLOATING POINT BUTTON CODE:
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="#0578C4"
        app:fabCustomSize="80dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>
```

This is the code for how I want each menu item to look, but with the user's custom title rather than "Counter X" (X being 1,2,3 etc).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create an `ArrayList` with titles (assumed you know how to do that).
You probably need some other class than `String`, but let assuming a `String` is enough.

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>;
```

Then, on "Add" button of your dialog box

```
myList.add(theNewInsertedTitle);
invalidateOptionsMenu(); // this will recreate your options menu
```

Then, override your `onCreateOptionsMenu` from your Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem mnu = menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, Menu.NONE, myList.get(i));
        mnu.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view);
    }
    // this is needed if you want to show icons on options menu
    if(menu instanceof MenuBuilder) {  //To display sportId on overflow menu
        MenuBuilder m = (MenuBuilder) menu;
        m.setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
     }

    return true;
}
```

That's all...

Comment: well I have no clue what 98% of that meant but I'll do some googling to try to understand. I don't even know how strings work so mine probably aren't properly set up. Thanks though